# Why is anything I do as root temporary?

Tags: 14.04, server, login, password, root

#### Long story short:

On this server I had lost the password to the server root account, as well as a secondary non-root account. Thus, leaving me powerless to change the non-root password (or to do anything for that matter).

I've finally been able to login as root by changing the **Ubuntu 14.04** boot to have `rw init=/bin/bash` instead of `quiet ro splash`.

Unfortunately, anything I do as this root is completely *virtual* in a sense. Any files I create as root disappear the next login. Not to mention whilst logged in as root, all other accounts on the server apparently don't exist.

How can I recover (proper) server root access that **will** allow me to alter files/change passwords?

#### Other things to note:

- The bios and grub menu are password locked as well.

Comment: Bios is password locked?

Comment: @George Yes, it displays the `Enter CURRENT Password:` screen.  3 tries and it locks you out.

Comment: See: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000235.htm and http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-a-BIOS-Password

Comment: I am guessing either your root directory is ro, some sort of cow, or you dual boot with windows and have fast boot enabled.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Perhaps. Not the ladder however. Purely Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to "single user mode" by adding `single` after `quiet ro splash`.
You should then be able to set the root password.

Just replacing the init system with bash might not do quite what you need since it is just dropping straight to the shell and not initializing the system as it normally would.

Comment: Just tried that. It asks for the root password for maintenance `or press Ctrl-D to continue`. After continuing it leaves me with a screen with a few logs and no access of typing anything.